# Generic method named Max that takes 2 parameters and returns greater of 2 reference types

Tags: c#-4.0

In C# Language Write a generic method named Max that takes 2 parameters and returns greater of 2 values. Apply constraint to support only reference types.Test it against Employee class which has salary as the property of type int.Max should compare two employee instances based on the salary and return employee instance which has greater salary.
This is what I have done How should i proceed further...?

```
using System;  
using System.Collections.Generic;   
using System.Text;  

namespace Generic_Max_of_Salary
{
    class Program   
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            runtest();                
        }

        public static void runtest()    
        {
            Test_Maximum(new Employee { Salary = 10000 }, new Employee { Salary = 20000 }, new Employee { Salary = 20000 }, 1);
            Test_Maximum(new Employee { Salary = 30000 }, new Employee { Salary = 20000 }, new Employee { Salary = 30000 }, 2);
            Test_Maximum(new Employee { Salary = 10000 }, new Employee { Salary = 10000 }, new Employee { Salary = 10000 }, 3);    
        }

        public static void Test_Maximum(Employee emp1, Employee emp2, Employee obtained_answer, int testcase)
        {
            Employee expected_answer = Maximum<Employee>(emp1, emp2);

            if (CompareTo(obtained_answer, expected_answer))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Test " + testcase + " Passed");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Test " + testcase + " Failed");
            }
        }

        public static T Maximum<T>(T emp1, T emp2)
        {

            if (emp1.Salary >= emp2.Salary)
            {
                return emp1;
            }
            else
            {
                return emp2;
            }
        }

        public static bool CompareTo(Employee obtained_answer, Employee expected_answer)
        {
            if (obtained_answer.Salary == expected_answer.Salary)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }            
    }

    class Employee
    {
        public int Salary { get; set; }    
    }
}
```

Comment: This won't compile as your generic method `Maximum<T>` tries to access a property `Salary` on the unbound (open?) type `T`.

Comment: So what is your concrete question? Where are you stuck? Which part of the assignment gives you the problem?

Comment: I am not able to access the Salary Property through emp1 or emp2..!! How can I access the property?

Comment: That's because the compiler does not know that the open type `T` has a property called `Salary`. You can either add a constraint to `T` that it needs to be a derived class of `Employee` or you need to call the `Maximum` function with the salaries instead of the employee instances.

Comment: public static Employee Maximum(Employee emp1, Employee emp2)
        {
            if (emp1.Salary >= emp2.Salary)
            {
                return emp1;
            }
            else
            {
                return emp2;
            }

        }                                                            This is how i did without generics..!!! I want to make it generic. Sorry If My questions look too simple just send me links where I can learn those concepts.

Comment: Thanks a lot I got it working..!!! by adding a constraint to T that it needs to be a derived class of Employee....

Comment: I added my solution as answer so you can accept it and mark this question as closed =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the compiler does not know that the open type `T` has a property called `Salary`. You can either add a constraint to `T` that it needs to be a derived class of `Employee` or you need to call the `Maximum` function with the salaries instead of the employee instances.

```
public static T Maximum<T>(T emp1, T emp2) where T: Employee
{
    if (emp1.Salary >= emp2.Salary)
    {
        return emp1;
    }
    else
    {
        return emp2;
    }
}
```

Just to elaborate on the question, a generic function only constraining on reference type like

```
static T Maximum<T>(T obj1, T obj2) where T : class
{
    if (obj1 > obj2)
    {
        return obj1;
    }

    return obj2;
}
```

does not work as the `>` operator is not defined on `T`. Your best chance is to check if the input objects are `IComparable` or `Employees`:

```
static T Maximum<T>(T obj1, T obj2) where T : class
{
    if (obj1 is Employee && obj2 is Employee)
    {
        if (((Employee)obj1).Salary > ((Employee)obj2).Salary)
        {
            return obj1;
        }

        return obj2;
    }

    if (obj1 is IComparable && obj2 is IComparable)
    {
        if (((IComparable)obj1).CompareTo(obj2) > 0)
        {
            return obj1;
        }

        return obj2;
    }

    throw new NotSupportedException("Cannot compare two reference types without knowledge of the type.");
}
```

Comment: Calling Maximum(emp1.salary,emp2.salary2)                             How will you make this function return the instance of employee with greater salary.Can you elaborate on the second method you mentioned about?